# How to send a file to backend in react-native using node.js

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I tried

```js
const myData = uri; // this looks like file:///data/expo/...

const myDataResponse = await API.SendFile({
    myData: myData
});
```

But file is not being recieved in the backend. Is there any other way to do this?

IN the backend I get

```js
console.log(req.body)
// I get a string same as uri of file
console.log(req.file)
// undefined
```

Backend is setup perfectly. I am getting successful response when using postman.

Any help is appreciated. I am a begginer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use FormData.

```
const data = new FormData();
// first argument is the key name received on you API
// second argument is your file path
data.append('file', filePath)
// then your request should look like this :
await fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
},
    body: data,
})
```

Comment: can you show me your request and your route please ?